# Permalink not changing according to post type

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, seo, site-url, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using two post types:

a) Posts ( Default post type) also name as blog for blogging.

b) case studies ( Custom Post Type ) only for case studies.

I want to add the string ‘blog’ for default post type post and ‘casestudies’ for custom post type like:

example.com/blog/post-name/

example.com/casestudies/case-study-name/

right now i have selected /%postname%/ as my permalink structure. but it is only picking **example.com/casestudies/case-study-name/** url for case study post type and for blog it is displaying example.com/post-name. when i change permalink to **blog/%postname%/** it also changes url structure for case study post type as **example.com/blog/casestudies/case-study-name/**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Permalink structure for blog posts and pages are managed in Wordpress `Settings -> Permalinks` page, so to make blog posts have permalinks like `blog/%postname%/` and you've done it right.

The tricky part is about Custom Post type permalinks declaration:

in your CPT arguments declaration there's a `rewrite` rule  parameters, which in turn has `with_front` - if this parameter is `false` you'll have permalink structure without prefix used for blog posts, and if it's `true` you'll have what you've experienced. By default it's set to `true`.

So fixed part of rewrite parameter will look like.

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug'       => 'casestudies', // your case studies permalink base.
    'with_front' => false, // important to make your links without base of blog posts.
    'pages'      => true, // set true if you need pagination for your cpt listing.
),
```